# how to differentiate two submit button for sweetalert in a single form

Tags: html, jquery, flask, sweetalert

I don't know how to differentiate the two button in sweetalert

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" id="deleteform" action="/">
        <input type="hidden" name="amccode" id="amccode" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="test1_id" name="test1" type="submit">TEST1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="test2_id" name="test2" type="submit">TEST2</button>
</form>
<script>
$('#test1_id').on('click',function(e) {

    event.preventDefault();
var form = $(this).parents('form');

        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "All data related to this AMC ID will be parmanently deleted",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
          form.submit();
          } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "ha :)", "error");

  }
});
});


$('#test2_id').on('click',function(e) {

    event.preventDefault();
var form = $(this).parents('form');

        swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "TEST2",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
          form.submit();
          } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "ha :)", "error");

  }
});
});

</script>
```

in the code to handle form, I can't get name="test1" or name="test2" info , so the two button can't be differentiated , so I want to handle action1 when press button1,and handle action2 when press button2

my backed code is

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "assa"


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def single_input():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.form)
        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

I can't get which response is from test1, which is from test2

Comment: Hi, so you need to change `action` value inside form depending on buttons i.e : test1,test2 ?

Comment: Hi,Swati, yes, you got my question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use attr to get attribute of element

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

```js
$('#test1_id').on('click',function(e) {
  var getNameAttr = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(getNameAttr);
  
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form');

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "All data related to this AMC ID will be parmanently deleted",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
      form.submit();
    } else {
      swal("Cancelled", "ha :)", "error");
    }
  });
});


$('#test2_id').on('click',function(e) {
  var getNameAttr = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(getNameAttr);
  
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form');

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "TEST2",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
      form.submit();
    } else {
      swal("Cancelled", "ha :)", "error");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" id="deleteform" action="/">
  <input type="hidden" name="amccode" id="amccode" value="1">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="test1_id" name="test1" type="submit">TEST1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="test2_id" name="test2" type="submit">TEST2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just update my question, I can't get the "test1" or "test2" info after submit the form

Comment: @user1334609 This answer is almost right . Just add `form.attr("action",getNameAttr)` to change action of form inside `if (isConfirm) {..` or add some hidden input with these values .

Comment: Hi Swait, I want to use single backend function, can I use a variable to judge it ?

Comment: @user1334609 Yes or if you are changing action you can check if inside url `test1` or `test2` exist depending on  this change your logic i.e : `if 'test1' in request.path` something like that .

Comment: Hi Swait , but how test1 or test2 pass to backend ?